# Weekend parking at PATCO stations

Tags: public-transport, automobiles, new-jersey, philadelphia

Nowhere on the [PATCO](http://www.ridepatco.org/) website or elsewhere (TripAdvisor, etc.) can I seem to find information about parking at PATCO Speedline stations on weekends. Are the lots open? Is there a fee?

The only information about parking fees is available, somewhat non-intuitively, on the station map popup windows, e.g. [Haddonfield](http://www.ridepatco.org/stations/haddonfield_parking.html). It says

> Gated Parking - $1 from 5 am to 10 am (pay with FREEDOM card in Lots N1, N2, N3, S1, and S2). Free after 10 am.

I may *assume* that the fees for gated parking are only applicable during the workweek, although nowhere is this explicitly stated, as they seem targeted at commuters.

There is no indication, however, as to whether the gated parking areas are available on weekends, or whether the gates are closed. I once drove up to Ashland on a Sunday and had to circle a bit because half the lot was closed, but that was years and years ago, and may have been for maintenance as opposed to a general policy.

If it is different station-by-station, I am specifically interested in Haddonfield on a Saturday morning in April. My conference hotel wants $55 to park in its garage in Philadelphia, which, with bridge tolls from New Jersey, makes the transit option very appealing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it happens, I passed through the area last weekend and parked at Ferry Avenue to see for myself.

Gated parking is indeed open and free on weekends, but not obviously so. The gates are closed, but if you drive up to one, ignoring all the signs about needing a payment card, it will simply open automatically for you. Exiting is the same.

The free lots, which are not gated, are also open, but of course a little farther away.